# Redux Form gives an infinite loop after filling in all fields

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am using same fields on page in two scenarios and validation gives me an infinite loop.
It gives me an infinite loop only when validation has been triggered and all fields have been filled in.
I am wondering how can I write validations differently.

Here are my validations:

```
  const partnerEmail = (value) => {
    const mainEmail = _get(mainApplicantValues, 'email', null);

    return mainEmail && value === mainEmail
      ? 'Email address must not be the same as your partner'
      : '';
  };

  const partnerPhone = (value) => {
    const mainPhone = _get(mainApplicantValues, 'mobileNumber', null);

    return mainPhone && value === mainPhone
      ? 'Mobile number must not be the same as your partner'
      : '';
  };
```

Here are my fields which I call on the same page conditionally:

```
  <Grid item lg={12} xs={12}>
    <Field
      name={`${name}.mobileNumber`}
      component={MyTextField}
      label="YOUR MOBILE NUMBER"
      validate={
        isPartner ? [required, phone, partnerPhone] : [required, phone]
      }
    />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item lg={12} xs={12}>
    <Field
      name={`${name}.email`}
      component={MyTextField}
      label="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
      validate={
        isPartner ? [required, email, partnerEmail] : [required, email]
      }
    ></Field>
  </Grid>
```

my dependencies:

```
    "redux-form": "^8.3.6",
    "redux-form-input-masks": "^2.0.1",
    "redux-form-validators": "^3.3.2",
```

Comment: Are the validation functions inside the render method?

Comment: I am using functional components, so I think answer is yes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the validation functions inside the render method or using functional components with everything inside of it, maybe the problem is that when you change the value of the field and the validation function is triggered, it renders the component again, changing the validation function and forcing the component to render again, entering in an infinite loop.

You can check this [Redux-Form GitHub Issue](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/4148), as they present a problem that is similar to yours.